# Sending Instant email notifications to attendees for insert and delete events via Google Calendar API

Tags: node.js, email, google-calendar-api

Here with the below code i was able to send notification mail 1 hour before the event, my objective is to send instant mails to the mentioned attendees on addition of any event or deletion. Can anyone help with this?

```js
function insertHoliday(auth) {
  const calendar = google.calendar({ version: googleCalendarVersion, auth });

  calendar.events.insert(
    {
      auth: auth,
      calendarId: calendarID,
      resource: {
        'summary': name,
        'start': {
          'dateTime': date + workStartTime,
          'timeZone': timeRegion
        },
        'end': {
          'dateTime': date + workEndTime,
          'timeZone': timeRegion
        },
      },
      attendees: [{ email: 'menonujra@gmail.com' }],
      reminders: {
          useDefault: false,
          overrides: [{ method: 'email', minutes: 24 * 60 },{ method: 'popup', minutes: 10 }]
      }
    }, async function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
        logger.info('There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err);
        return;
      }
      logger.info('Holiday Event Created');

      let properties = {
         event_id: res.data.id,
      }

      await holidayModel.updateHolidayById(uuid, properties);

    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Are the event deletions going to be done via the API? You could create a `sendMail(attendees)` template function which sends the mail using the Gmail API, you would just need to handle your atendees in a separate array and pass them through.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "sendUpdates" Optional query parameters when creating an event.

Click [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) to read more about it.